# reactjs a onclick bind error , what can ı do?

Tags: reactjs

When ı click the  a tag , mysort function is not working , Why does not work?

class Navbar extends Component {

```
        mysort=(e)=>{

            e.preventDefault()
            var ks= e.sort(function(a,b){
                return a-b;
            });
            console.log(ks)
        }   

      render(){

        var dizi=[4,2,56,42,23,15]

            return(
                <div>
                    <a href="" onClick={this.mysort.bind(this,dizi)}> CLİCK </a>
                </div>
            )
      }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean *"not working"*?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using an **arrow function**  *mysort()*, you don't need to bind it explicitly. 
Just use below syntax in your onClick event handler

```
<a href="" onClick={(e) => this.mysort(e,dizi)}> CLİCK </a>
```

Refer this link to for more information https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-do-i-pass-a-parameter-to-an-event-handler-or-callback

Answer (score 0):

```
class Navbar extends Component {

  mysort = (e,dizi) => {

    e.preventDefault()
    var ks = dizi.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a - b;
    });
    console.log(ks)
  }

  render() {

    var dizi = [4, 2, 56, 42, 23, 15]

    return ( 
   <div>
      <a href = "" onClick = {e =>this.mysort(e,dizi)}> CLİCK </a> 
</div>
    )
  }
}
```

You can use arrow function to bind implicitly and in your mysort function, your are trying to access e.sort which indeed was trying to use event previously. Now pass on dizi array and your mysort function should work.